# I want to read a string of type "t = 10" in Obj C, and take the value of the character and the value of the integer. What is the best way to do that?

Tags: objective-c, string

I want to read a string of type "t = 10" in Obj C, and take the value of the character and the value of the integer. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: So you want to **parse** the string? Does whitespace matter?

Comment: Exactly, yes whitespace matters.

Comment: @userXXX is the first part a single character only or there may be a word, even multiple words then space-equalsign-space then the number?

Comment: single lowercase letter, nothing else

Comment: thanks, can I still use scanner if t was longer than a character?

Comment: yes. But for this, please read NSScanner's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSScanner for that:

```
NSScanner *scn = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"t = 10"];
NSString *theChar;
[scn scanUpToString:@" = " intoString:&theChar];
[scn scanString:@" = " intoString:NULL];
int n;
[scn scanInt:&n];
```

here `theChar` will contain an `NSString` object containing the char and `n` will contain the numerical value of the integer.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize stack variables : `NSString *theChar = nil;`

Comment: @Taum not necessary. It'll be initialized by the scanner object, since it's passed byref.

Comment: It's funny because I always thought that would crash because scanUpToString:intoString: would try to release theChar before setting it. Apparently I was wrong and it doesn't (I just tried it).

You'd still run into trouble if it didn't change theChar and you tried to use it letter. Initializing stack variables is a general good practice that should always be done IMHO, as it avoids a lot of infrequent, hard to reproduce crashes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok_r.html), which is part of the C standard library.
It's slightly complicated, but should do a good portion of your work for you.

The `"t"`, `"="`, and `"10"` are what the docs refer to as "tokens", whereas the whitespace is the "separator".

If you don't care about the `"="`, you could have `strtok` treat that as a separator, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your string to NSArray

```
// separate the string to array by the = sign
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="]

// get the character
NSString *character = [myArray ObjectAtIndex:0];
// remove the whitespaces from the character
character = [character stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

// get the value
NSString *value= [myArray ObjectAtIndex:1];
// remove the whitespaces from the value
value= [value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

hope it helps :)